# Tasksheduling в С#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl

Заранее извиняюсь за столь длинный вопрос. Разбираюсь c `Task` и `TaskScheduler`. Я не уверен, что я правильно понимаю смысла существования `TaskScheduler`. Как я вижу ситуацию с ним, т.к `TaskScheduler` является абстрактным, мы не можем создавать его напрямую, поэтому у нас есть следующие два способа его создания:

1. унаследовать `TaskScheduler` и переопределить метод `QueueTask`
   который должен запускать задачу отложено;
2. получить экземпляр `TaskScheduler` с помощью
   `TaskScheduler.Default`.

Потом экземпляр `TaskScheduler` мы отправляем в конструктор `TaskFactory` и после этого мы на экземпляре `TaskFactory` вызывается метод `StartNew`, в который мы передаем нашу отложенную задачу. И тут `StartNew` вызывает `QueueTask` (метод который находится в `TaskScheduler` и который мы возможно переопределили) и вот `QueueTask` задает отложенный вызов нашей задачи которую мы передали в `StartNew`. Вот на основе этого возникли следующие ВОПРОСЫ:

1. Исходя из выше сканого у меня сложилось впечатление, что
   `TaskScheduler` вовсе никакой не планировщик задач, а просто прослойка
   между запускам задачи и ее началом выполнения. Он просто делает так,
   что бы  `StartNew` (метод `TaskFactory`) запускал не саму задачу, а
   метод `QueueTask` в котором я сам должен сделать всю логику
   планирования. Получается он не имеет какую-то внутреннюю логику по
   запуску задач отложено. Нет, я понимаю, он имеет потому, что я сам
   ее написал в методе `QueueTask`, но по факту `TaskScheduler` это лишь
   механизм внедрения МОЕГО собственного планировщика. Я правильно
   понимаю или же я чего-то не знаю?
2. Если я создам `TaskScheduler` через `TaskScheduler.Default` какая
   реализация будет у `QueueTask`? Как я понял он просто сразу запускает
   задачу...
3. В примерах с QueueTask  кроме отложенного запуска задачи делают
   добавление этой задачи в очередь... Зачем? Мы к примеру задали
   отложенную задачу с помощью `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`
   т.е все, мы отправили туда callback. Второй раз мы уже не можем
   запустить эту задачу, зачем нам ее хранить? Я лишь предполагаю, что
   мы ее храним лишь для возможного контроля ее, до запуска.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Начнем с того, что `Task` -- это абстракция задачи, которая
   ничего не говорит о том, где и кем будет выполнена задача. Этим как
   раз управляет `TaskScheduler`. Как вы верно заметили, класс
   `TaskScheduler` является абстрактным, а значит, конкретная логика
   заключена в его наследниках. А вот `TaskFactory` (и метод
   `Task.Run()`) -- это действительно прослойка между задачей и
   планировщиком.
2. Самый очевидный наследник -- `TaskScheduler.Default`. Это
   [планировщик пула потоков](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs,ede3f49dfeb3b299,references). Он выполняет порученные задачи в
   потоках из пула потоков. Время старта задачи при этом никак не
   оговаривается. Второй пример -- это группа планировщиков, которые
   предоставляет текущий синхронизационный контекст -- 
   `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` (например,
   ASP.NET, WinForms или WPF). Соответственно задача, которая была
   передана, например, планировщику WinForms, будет выполнена в главном
   (UI) потоке.
3. Покажите пример.

P.S. В 99% случаев достаточно вызывать `Task.Run()` и не связываться с `TaskFactory`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)  К сожалению пример я не могу предоставить. Знаете я asp.net mvc разработчик и меня кое-что заинтересовало в вашем ответе FromCurrentSynchronizationContext , ui поток (складывается впечатление, что это какой-то метод отвечающий за отрисовку и он запускается во вторичном потоке) я честно не понимаю, что это. Может Вы знаете какую-нибудь хорошую статью про эти вещи ?

Comment: @Snuppi не за что. В общем почитать можете [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/232169/). [Вот здесь](http://vegetarianprogrammer.blogspot.co.at/2012/12/understanding-synchronizationcontext-in.html) есть про контекст в ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, параллельно к `TaskScheduler.Default` есть ещё `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` (который в главном потоке WPF и WinForms создают scheduler, выполняющий задания в этом самом потоке). Кроме того, использовать `TaskScheduler` можно и в других местах, например, в `Task.ContinueWith`, ну и `await` тоже пользуется им под капотом.

Можно смотреть на `TaskScheduler` как на «прослойку» между отправкой таска на выполнение и самим выполнением. Но это собственно и есть смысл «планировки»: вы поставляете таск, а как и когда он будет запущен — вопрос, который решает планировщик (scheduler). То есть `TaskScheduler` — это не механизм внедрения вашего планировщика, *это и есть планировщик*!

> Получается он не имеет какую-то внутреннюю логику по запуску задач отложено

Не получается. Ваш метод `QueueTask` — часть `TaskScheduler`'а, это и есть вызов внутренней логики по запуску задач!

> Если я создам `TaskScheduler` через `TaskScheduler.Default` какая реализация будет у `QueueTask`

`TaskScheduler.Default` — планировщий на пуле потоков. Он просто выполнит [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx).

Из [исходников .NET](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs.html#33cd274e06874569):

```
protected internal override void QueueTask(Task task)
{
    if ((task.Options & TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning) != 0)
    {
        // Run LongRunning tasks on their own dedicated thread.
        Thread thread = new Thread(s_longRunningThreadWork);
        thread.IsBackground = true; // Keep this thread from blocking process shutdown
        thread.Start(task);
    }
    else
    {
        // Normal handling for non-LongRunning tasks.
        bool forceToGlobalQueue = ((task.Options & TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness) != 0);
        ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueCustomWorkItem(task, forceToGlobalQueue);
    }
}
```

> В примерах с QueueTask кроме отложенного запуска задачи делают добавление этой задачи в очередь... Зачем?

Это нужно спрашивать у авторов примера — скорее всего, в коде примера видно, откуда ещё производится доступ к очереди. `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, например, в `QueueTask` ничего не добавляет.